# How to use sinkTo in Flink to write multi file in AWS S3

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-flink, parquet, flink-streaming

i want to save data of many customers in different files.

Now, data is being stored in DataStream variable. How to use sinkTo to write multi file in AWS S3. Each file contains the data of a customer and the file name is the customer name.

```
public static void writeMultiFile(DataStream<Tuple5<String, Long, Double, String, String>> data) throws Exception {
    String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    Path pathNew = new Path(currentDir + "/output/");

    OutputFileConfig config = OutputFileConfig
            .builder()
            .withPartPrefix("namefile")
            .withPartSuffix(".parquet")
            .build();

    final FileSink<GenericRecord> sink = FileSink
            .forBulkFormat(pathNew, AvroParquetWriters.forGenericRecord(schema))
            .withOutputFileConfig(config)
            .build();

    data.keyBy(value->value.f0).map(new convertGenericRecord()).sinkTo(sink);
}
```

I need the file names to change by key. The code above can't do that, filename must be predefined, it cannot be changed dynamically by key.

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by implementing a `BucketAssigner`.

Something along these lines:

```java
public static final class KeyBucketAssigner
        implements BucketAssigner<Event, String> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 987325769970523326L;

    @Override
    public String getBucketId(final Event element, final Context context) {
        return String.valueOf(Event.key);
    }

    @Override
    public SimpleVersionedSerializer<String> getSerializer() {
        return SimpleVersionedStringSerializer.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

[documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/sink/filesystem/BucketAssigner.html)
[javadocs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/connectors/datastream/filesystem/#bucket-assignment)

Comment: Thank your answer. What is Event package belong to?

Comment: Event is just an example. Replace Event with whatever data type you are sending to the sink. And then in getBucketId return whatever you want to have included in the bucket's filenames.